# "Cannot read property" após uma requisição http.get

Tags: angularjs, ionic, restful, http-request

Olá, tudo bem?

Estou com o seguinte problema. Eu estou fazendo uma requisição RESTful (http.get) e estou gravando o objeto recebido em uma váriavel dentro do $scope. Porém, quando tento acessar esta variável dentro do controller recebo o seguinte erro:

Meu controller:

```
.controller('chartEvapo', function($http, $scope) {
  $http.get(meurepositorio)
    .success(function(response) {
      angular.forEach(response, function(response) {
        $scope.cityOBJ = response;
      });
    });

    var teste = $scope.cityOBJ.info.etppri;
})
```

E o erro:

> Cannot read property 'info' of undefined

O que acho estranho é que consigo imprimir os valores da seguinte forma:

```
<div>
  {{cityOBJ.info.etppri}}
</div>
```

O retorno de console.log(response) é:

```
 Object{_id: Object, id:"1", info:Object"}
 _id: Object
 id: "1"
 info: Object
 __proto__: Object
```

EDIT:

Com o seguinte controller tive o seguinte erro:

```
.controller('chartEvapo', function($http, $scope) {
var teste;

$http
    .get(meurepositorio)
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.cityOBJ = response;
        atualizaTeste();
    });

// está função ira atualizar a variável teste para você
function atualizaTeste() {
    this.teste = $scope.cityOBJ.info.etppri;
}
});
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'etppri' of undefined
>       at atualizaTeste (controllers.js)

EDIT 2:
Com o JSON.stringify;

```
  function atualizaTeste() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.cityOBJ));
    this.teste = $scope.cityOBJ.info.etppri;
}
```

Retorno no console:

> [{"_id":{"$oid":"5807a914dcba0f490c71818b"},"id":"1","info":{"etppri":[10,112,10,112,10,14,10,112,10,155,142,50],"etppen":["10","11","12","132","3","2","80","60","55","22","112","15"],"etptho":["10","11","12","132","3","2","80","60","55","22","112","15"],"bh":{"ex":["30","30","30","30","30","20","80","30","35","22","30","35"],"pr":["30","30","30","30","30","20","80","30","35","22","30","35"]}}}]

Comment: Não coloque "Resolvido" no título da pergunta. O mecanismo de marcar como útil já tem essa finalidade. Leia mais [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5389/resolvido-em-t%C3%ADtulo-de-pergunta-n%C3%A3o-fica-parecendo-coisa-de-f%C3%B3rum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renan, use seu `controller` desta maneira para vermos se resolverá o problema.

```
.controller('chartEvapo', function($http, $scope) {
    var teste;

    $http
        .get(meurepositorio)
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.cityOBJ = response;
            atualizaTeste();
        });

    // está função ira atualizar a variável teste para você
    function atualizaTeste() {
        this.teste = $scope.cityOBJ[0].info.etppri;
    }
});
```

Estou pensando que talvez o erro aconteça pelo fato do `$http` e `angular.forEach` serem assíncronos

Comment: Tive o seguinte erro: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'etppri' of undefined at atualizaTeste"

Comment: @RenanNunesSteinck certo, o erro aconteceu por que `info` está `undefined`. experimenta dar um `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.cityOBJ))` antes do `this.teste = ...` para vermos o que o objeto `cityOBJ` possui de propriedades.

Comment: Retornou isso: [{"_id":{"$oid":"5807a914dcba0f490c71818b"},"id":"1","info":{"etppri":[10,112,10,112,10,14,10,112,10,155,142,50],"etppen":["10","11","12","132","3","2","80","60","55","22","112","15"],"etptho":["10","11","12","132","3","2","80","60","55","22","112","15"],"bh":{"ex":["30","30","30","30","30","20","80","30","35","22","30","35"],"pr":["30","30","30","30","30","20","80","30","35","22","30","35"]}}}].

Comment: @RenanNunesSteinck altere o corpo da função `atualizaTeste` para `this.teste = $scope.cityOBJ[0].info.etppri;`. Irei fazer um edit na resposta. O objeto `cityOBJ` é na verdade um `array`, dessa forma, precisamos pegar o index 0.

Comment: Ótimo, para o que eu preciso isso já é o suficiente, porém, se eu quiser pegar o objeto inteiro, sem ter que identificar o índiceno vetor, é possível?

Comment: @RenanNunesSteinck se eu não estou enganado, e o OnoSendai pode me confirmar, o response já vem como `array`, se isso não for verdade, terá que ver na sua `API` o retorno do `JSON`. Então, assumindo que o response transforma automaticamente a resposta do servidor em um `array` você não tem escolha, mas pode usar um `for` ou pode pegar logo no `success` o `response[0]`, ai seu `$scope.cityOBJ` será um `object` lindo!

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece porque o objeto retornado no *callback* possui várias propriedades. A que lhe interessa é **`data`**, que contém o corpo da resposta retornada.

Altere seu código da seguinte maneira:

```
$scope.cityOBJ = response.data;
```

[Você pode encontrar mais informações a respeito do objeto de resposta aqui](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: O erro persiste. Quando faço "console.log(response.data)

Comment: O erro persiste. Quando faço "console.log(response.data);" aparece "undefined".

Comment: @RenanNunesStenck Poderia incluir na sua pergunta o objeto retornado? (`console.log(response);`)

Comment: Coloquei o resultado do console.log, Além disso (não sei se ajuda), mas o objeto que estou retornando é apenas um objeto (não um array), estou fazendo um get com o "id" (não _id) como chave de pesquisa. O servidor de banco que estou usando é o mlab.